# Can I join the KTable produced by a Kafka Streams #aggregate call before the aggregation runs?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a number of IOT devices that report events via messages to a kafka topic, and I have defined an aggregator to update the device state from those events.

What I'd like to do is be able to join the input stream to the KTable that the aggregator outputs before the aggregation updates the state-- that is, I want to, say, compare an event to the current state, and if they match a certain predicate, do some processing, and then update the state.

I've tried creating the state store with `StreamsBuilder#addStateStore` first, but that method returns a StreamsBuilder, and doesn't seem to provide me a way to turn it into a KTable.

I've tried joining the input stream against the KTable produced by `StreamsBuilder#aggregate`, but that doesn't do what I want, because it only gives me the value in the KTable after the aggregation has run, and I'd like it to run before the aggregation.

```java
// this is fine, but it returns a StreamsBuilder and I don't see how to get a KTable out of it
streamsBuilder.addStateStore(
  Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
      Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(deviceStateAggregator),
      Serdes.String(),
      Serdes.String()
  )
);

// this doesn't work because I only get doThingsBeforeStateUpdate called after the state is updated by the DeviceStateAggregator
KTable<String, DeviceState> deviceTable = deviceEventKStream
  .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), new deviceEventSerde()))
  .aggregate(
    () -> null,
    new DeviceStateAggregator(),
    Materialized.<String, DeviceState>as(stateStoreSupplier)
      .withValueSerde(deviceStateSerde)
  );
deviceEventKStream.join(deviceTable, (event, state) -> doThingsBeforeStateUpdate(event, state));
```

I was hoping to be able to exploit the Streams DSL to check some preconditions before the state is updated by the aggregator, but it doesn't seem possible. I'm currently exploring the idea of using a Processor, or perhaps just extending my DeviceStateAggregator to do all the pre-aggregation processing as well, but that feels awkward to me, as it forces the aggregation to care about concerns that don't seem reasonable to do as part of the aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that is, I want to, say, compare an event to the current state, and if they match a certain predicate, do some processing, and then update the state.

If I understand your question and notably this quote correctly, then I'd follow your idea to use the Processor API to implement this. You will need to implement a `Transformer` (as you want it to output data, not just read it).

As an example application that you could use as a starting point I'd recommend to look at the `MixAndMatch DSL + Processor API` and the `CustomStreamTableJoin` examples at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples. The second example shows, though for a different use case, how to do custom "if this then that" logic when working with state in the Processor API, plus it also covers join functionality, which is something you want to do, too.

Hope this helps!